# How to read and write the raw device file of a usb flash drive as non-root

Tags: linux, file-io, device, root

My USB flash drive gets automatically mounted at `/media/ME` without requiring `root` intervention.

Now, I can read and write sectors on the drive mounted at `/dev/sdX` device using `open`, `lseek`, `read`, and `write`. But I can do this only as `root`.

Question: Just as the device can get mounted without `root` intervention, is it also possible to read and write from/to this device without being `root`?

<strike>If it's not possible, I'm willing to show a GUI password dialog for `root`. But how do I do this from my console program?</strike>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

The block device /dev/sdX has standard UNIX permissions - so if it is owned by your user or a group your user is in and the permissions are set correctly then you will be able to write to it.

```
$ ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 0 Dec  3 18:27 /dev/sda
```

So only root and members of the group disk can read or write to my /dev/sda. If I put myself in the disk group I would be able to write to the block device.

You can set-up udev to set the permission of the block devices automagically when they are plugged in.